# Do we ignore weight of the rod in vertical spring-block system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram, spring

> Problem: The first spring is placed at the
> middle of the rod and the second one at the end as shown in the figure. If the end of the rod is slightly pulled up and released,
> determine the angular frequency of small oscillations.

[image: Figure]

My professor said "We ignore the weight since the initial elongation of the spring will be cancelled by the weight of the rod", and hence her differential equations of motion don't contain any gravity term while mine do .

Could someone tell or hopefully explain which one of us is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence "end of the rod is slightly pulled up and released"

presumably means, "slightly pulled up (from the equilibrium position)..."

The extension/compression of the springs would adjust to take into account the weight of the rod, before the slight lift.

So your teacher was right.

After being released, it's just the change in the extension or compression of the springs that matter, not how far they were extended or compressed to start with.  So a gravity term isn't needed, you would however need a mass term, or moment of inertia of the rod.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. my intuition tells me it helps the rod come down, and hinders it as it goes up . So gravity doesn't affect the "steady-state" motion -so to speak- , at all ?

Comment: @ Ait-Gacem Nabil There would be an extra compression of the spring underneath providing say $6N$ up and an extra stretch of the spring above providing e.g. $4N$ up, both before the "slight pull down".  These forces would balance the weight.  Then let's say the pull down was $0.5cm$ providing an extra force from each spring and they become $6.1N$ and $4.2N$, then the net upward force is still from the $0.1N$ and $0.2N$ as the $6N$ and $4N$ parts just balance the weight as before...

Answer (score 1):

The *static* forces in the structure are indeterminate. The unstretched lengths of the springs and the position of the fixed points is not given, so you don't know the three reaction forces on the rod, or the bending moments inside the rod.

However, all those forces cancel out in dynamic equations of motion, in exactly the same way as they do in the statics equation.

Maybe your confusion is because you included *some* of the static forces (i.e. the weight) but ignored the others, and therefore you think the motion depends on the weight.

Note, of course the motion depends on the *mass* of the rod (and presumably $I$ in the figure is the moment of inertia of the rod about the pivot at the left hand end), but mass and weight are two different things!